# Get all the child nodes of parent nodes

Tags: mysql, treeview, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I have a `treeview` that is rendered from [Kartik Tree Manager](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-tree-manager). Below is my tree view

[image]

**Table**

[image]

**What I want to do?**

I want to select all the child nodes of `Floor-1` via `MySQL` query

I have tried to run a query like below

```
SELECT * FROM `mdc_node` m 
WHERE m.`lft` = 11-2
```

**Output**

[image]

**Desired Output**

I want the following output

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| `id` | `root` | `lft` | `rgt` | `lvl` | `name`   | 'icon' |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 3    |    1   |   3   |    4  |   2   |GIS Office| folder |
| 4    |    1   |   5   |    6  |   2   |   Ali    |  user  |
| 5    |    1   |   7   |    8  |   2   |   Usman  |  user  |
| 6    |    1   |   9   |    10 |   2   |  Faisal  |  user  |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is my SQL Fiddle

[Node Table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d01591/1)

I want to select all the child nodes under the parent node

Comment: Please: replace the pictures with the CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (or create online fiddle); add desired output for posted data in textual table form; specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina I have added it

Comment: I do NOT see: 1) desired output for posted data in textual table form 2) precise MySQL version. The columns unrelated to the question may be skipped or (better) deleted from the fiddle.

Comment: @Akina I did need all the fields. Just to make things simpler I have just posted few of them. See my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to select all the child nodes of Floor-1 via MySQL query

> I want the following output

```sql
select * from mdc_node;

SELECT t1.id, t1.root, t1.lft, t1.rgt, t1.lvl, t1.name, t1.icon
-- from 1st copy of a table
FROM mdc_node t1
-- join 2nd copy of a table used for to get the info about needed parent
JOIN mdc_node t2
-- child nodes left and right are between left and right of their  parent
                ON t1.lft BETWEEN t2.lft AND t2.rgt
-- we need only the next level
                AND t1.lvl = t2.lvl + 1
-- specify parent
WHERE t2.name = 'Floor-1';
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d01591/8)

The only problem - I cannot understand why `icon` for a row `id=3` is `'folder'` in output whereas it is `'user'` in source data.

Comment: it is because the `Floor-1` is the `parent` of `user`

Comment: @Faisal If so I understand your storing structure wrongly it seems... all 4 nodes returned has the same level and the same parent - why `icon` is set to `'folder'` only for `id=3`? And in the screenshot, all 4 child nodes are completely equal and formally swappable...

Comment: the level will be always the same because the level starts with the parent whose level is `1` afterward whenever a new node is added its level will be `parent_level +1`. As for `icon`, I am following a hierarchy `Building=>Floor=>Customer`. You can further read it at [here](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-tree-manager)

Comment: I have added a new node then added a child under it. After that, I run your script. But It's showing me, 2nd node child, as well, here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a7b968/5)

Comment: @Faisal *I am following a hierarchy Building=>Floor=>Customer* I believe that Ali, Usman and Faisal are customers but I think that "GIS Office" is not a customer but it is office or firm or department or something else. And these 3 customers belongs to it. But if so then "GIS Office" only must be level 2 row, and another 3 nodes (Ali, Usman and Faisal) must be its child nodes with level = 3.

Comment: No the `GIS Office` is also a customer the name is written in this way and it can be changed. So all the 4 `GIS Office, Ali, Usman and Faisal` are customer

Comment: @Faisal If so why only `'GIS Office'` has `icon='folder'`? What data (specify the values in separate columns for separtate rows with explanation of the relation please) allows to distinguish which' icon must be altered?

Comment: `GIS Office` has `icon=user`. The `Floor-1` has `icon=Folder`. The main problem in this widget is the relation binding. It's not clearly understood. But if you know the id of parent you can check it's child but still, it got some issue with it like I am facing

Comment: @Faisal *I have added a new node then added a child under it. After that, I run your script. But It's showing me, 2nd node child, as well* Oops, the storing scheme is slightly another. The query edited - look.